# Loop (1+x+x**2+x**3+x**4....n) not working

Tags: python

SO i wrote this snippet but it doesn't seem to work.

```
x=1
sum1=0
n=int(input("enter how long the series should be"))
print (x)
for a in range (1,n):
   sum1=sum1+(sum1**a)
   print(sum1)
   a=a+1
print("the sum of the series is",sum1)
```

The output was:

```
enter how long the series should be5
1
0
0
0
0
the sum of the series is 0
>>>
```

Comment: You don't need to increment `a`

Comment: Don't you want `x**a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice you aren't using your input `x` anywhere in the loop. That's because `sum1 ** a` should be `x ** a`. Also, you want to use `range(1, n+1)`, as the second argument needs to be one larger than the largest value you want to produce.

Incrementing `a` as you are is harmless, but unnecessary; the `for` loop itself updates the value of `a` on each iteration. (Incrementing `a` at the *top* of the loop would cause problems, as `a` would have the wrong value when you use it in the calculation.)

Comment: Also do mention that he need not increment `a` in the loop and that the range must be from 1 to *n+1*

Answer (score 0):

use x in your equation `sum1=sum1+(sum1**a)`.
   So your modified eq should be `sum1=sum1+(x**a)`

```
x=1
sum1=0

n=int(input("enter how long the series should be"))
    print (x)
    for a in range (1,n):
    sum1=sum1+(x**a)
    print(sum1)
    a=a+1
print("the sum of the series is",sum1)
```

Comment: Please rephrase your sentence (the meaning is somewhat flipped) and correct the python indentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=1
sum1=0
n=int(input("enter how long the series should be"))
print (x)
for a in range (1,n):
   sum1 += (x**a)
   print(sum1)
print("the sum of the series is", sum1)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the poster's question; this answer is code only and doesn't provide any guidance why this works and the poster's code does not.